# BSOD Windows XP after loading logo

Tags: windows-xp, hard-drive, bsod

I've been getting BSOD after Windows XP loading logo.
Weird thing is if I try to reinstall Windows XP - the installation CD doesn't see the hard drive, but then why is it trying to load into Win XP?
The HDD LED seems to blink and during Boot Menu I see the Hard Disk option. I didn't drop the laptop or anything.
What could be wrong?

Comment: Even of the HDD lights are blinking, it sounds like a bad HDD

Comment: No. It's not...

Comment: when you goto bios, do you see the hard drive present? how can you be so sure?

Comment: Yes. The hard drive option is listed.

Comment: It could be that the hard drive is in AHCI mode. XP only comes with IDE drivers - how old is this laptop? Also, possibly the connector has worked itself loose.

Comment: Try a live Linux USB or CD. Start it up, run `gsmartcontrol` to diagnose the HDD and make sure it's physically OK, and if it still doesn't work, consider upgrading to something released this decade, like, I don't know, Windows 8 or 8.1.

Comment: @allquixotic Xp > 8.

Comment: lol windows 8 nice one

Comment: So, I just booted into Hiren's CD Live Linux Rescue Partition Magic utility and launched GParted. It seems my hard drive right there. What do I do now?

Comment: Why did you launch `gparted`? I said to run `gsmartcontrol` (alternatively `smartctl`, but that's a lot harder to use for a newbie). That tool will let you read the SMART diagnostics data off the hard disk to make sure it's physically OK. If it's OK, then you know that the problem with the Windows XP installer is related to software, and you'll need to get some kind of boot disk (probably a floppy disk, or a CD in the ideal case) with SATA/AHCI drivers for your hard drive, and tell the Windows XP installer that you "Have Disk".